# Can #undef reduce compiling time?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, coding-style, compilation

Can #undef reduce compilation time? I have thousands of macros and a 250k function, but they take up to 15 seconds to be parsed & compiled completely. Should I write code like this :

```
#define f_WM_SETFOCUS 0xF59EE0A2     
#define f_WM_KILLFOCUS 0xA4671283
#define f_WM_ENABLE 0x25A5D864

AddMacro('W', 'S',  f_WM_SETFOCUS, WM_SETFOCUS, ___INT);
AddMacro('W', 'S',  f_WM_KILLFOCUS, WM_KILLFOCUS, ___INT);
AddMacro('W', 'E',  f_WM_ENABLE, WM_ENABLE, ___INT);

#undef f_WM_SETFOCUS
#undef f_WM_KILLFOCUS
#undef f_WM_ENABLE

#define ...
```

Comment: Surely it's easy to try it and see what difference there is.

Comment: Thanks. I will try now. But are there any another solutions which can speedup my compiler? IMO the process is not easy...

Comment: 15 second compile time?! I wish I had your problems

Comment: Using precompiled headers can boost compilation time and is normal in Visual Studio projects.

Comment: By using a dedicated build machine and multi-threaded compilations, we've reduced our build time to just under 32 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no reason why it should reduce compilation time.
As those macros are once read there are probably kept in memory till the and of the world (i mean compilation) - but it's all compiler dependent so you probably just give it a chance and see what happens.

The thing you can do to avoid reading those macros all the time is to only include file with those macros into implementation files and never into any header (it is probably possible).
That way this file will only be read when those macros are actually used (that means only in compilation units that are using it).

HTH.

PS. 15 seconds compilation time is not so long anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, indeed #undef doesn't help me reduce compilation time...